# If OU name has this date dont create

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a AD cleanup script. What I want to happen is for the script run once a month and move all disabled accounts from that month into an OU under the disabled OU and label it with the date. For the most part it works. I would like help with adding logic to not try to create the new OU with the same date. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
$date=get-date -Format o
$date=$date.Split("T")
$date=$date[0]
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name $date -Path "OU=Disabled, DC=mydomain, DC=net" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$disabled = (get-aduser -filter * -properties lastlogondate | Where-Object 
{$_.enabled -eq $false -and $_.lastlogondate -lt (get-date).adddays(-90)} 
|select Name).name
foreach($user in $disabled)
{
Get-ADUser $user | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=$date, OU=Disabled, 
DC=mydomain, DC=net" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

Comment: Can `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit` be used to check to see if the OU already exists?

Answer (score 1):

As @lit is already onto I would do:

```
$existingOU = Get-AdOrganizationalUnit -filter { name -eq "$date" };
if($null -eq $existingOU) {
 "....do your New-AdOrgani.... cmdlet execution here...." }
```

I hope this helps and have a great 1 :-).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I come up with that does work but I'm going to try your way as well. Thanks for your post.

```
$date=get-date -Format o
$date=$date.Split("T")
$date=$date[0]
$disabled = (get-aduser -filter * -properties lastlogondate | Where-Object {$_.enabled -eq $false -and $_.lastlogondate -lt (get-date).adddays(-90)} |select Name).name
try {
New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name $date -Path "OU=Disabled, DC=mydomain, DC=net"
} catch {
#If we want another action
}
foreach($user in $disabled)
{
Get-ADUser $user | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=$date, OU=Disabled, DC=mydomain, DC=net" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```